# What happens to allies in the additional ally slots if Rod of Animalism leaves play?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

The [Rod of Animalism](https://arkhamdb.com/card/08128) says:

> You have 2 additional ally slots, which can only be used to hold Creature assets.

If I have 3 allies in play, like one [Beat Cop](https://arkhamdb.com/card/01518) and two [Guard dogs](https://arkhamdb.com/card/01521), and then [Crypt Chill](https://arkhamdb.com/card/01167) forces me to discard the [Rod of Animalism](https://arkhamdb.com/card/08128) that it's in play, what happens?

I will not have the two additional ally slots anymore, but does that mean that the ally assets in those slots do also **leave**?

The [Slots](https://arkhamdb.com/rules#Slots) rule says two things:

> Slots limit the number of asset cards the investigator is **permitted to have in play simultaneously**.

> If **playing or gaining control of an asset** would put an investigator above his or her slot limit for that type of asset, the investigator must choose and discard other assets under his or her control simultaneously with the new asset entering the slot.

I'm not sure if the check is **only** done at the time of **playing or gaining control** or that check must be done also at the moment the [Rod of animalism](https://arkhamdb.com/card/08128) leaves.

Answer (score 2):

I got the following answer from [reddit user ademre](https://www.reddit.com/r/arkhamhorrorlcg/comments/sxz7rv/comment/hxuvpxg/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

The FAQ section (taken from the official FAQ or FFG's responses to the official rules question form) for [Bandolier](https://arkhamdb.com/card/02147#reviews-header) says:

> If you lose an asset that grants you additional slots, you must discard cards in excess of those slots until you have a legal number of assets in play in those slots. For example, if you had a Bandolier, a Shotgun and a Machete in play, and the bandolier was discarded, you would be forced to discard either the shotgun or the machete.

> Slots are a constant restriction on the cards you can have in play, and something the game state constantly checks.